# How to use absolute position as relative?

Tags: html, css, position

I have a `<span>` with `position: absolute`. Also the next to it is a text. Now I want when the `width` of that span increases, then the space between both span and text increase too.

In other word, I don't want to Red-Color-Span cover "MyName" text **never**. How?

```css
.notification{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span class='inbox'>
    <span class='notification'></span>
    <i class="fa fa-inbox"></i>
    MyName
</span>

<br><br>
<span class='inbox'>
    <span class='notification'>23</span>
    <i class="fa fa-inbox"></i>
    MyName
</span>

<br><br>
<span class='inbox'>
    <span class='notification'>4245</span>
    <i class="fa fa-inbox"></i>
    MyName
    </span>
```

Actually I want something like this:

```css
.notification{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span class='inbox'>
    <span class='notification'></span>
    <i class="fa fa-inbox"></i>
    MyName
</span>

<br><br>
<span class='inbox'>
    <span class='notification'>23</span>
    <i class="fa fa-inbox"></i>
    MyName
</span>

<br><br>
<span class='inbox'>
    <span class='notification'>4245</span>
    <i class="fa fa-inbox"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    MyName
</span>
```

Comment: Why do you need absolute positioning?

Comment: @www139 I edited my question and add what I want ...!

Comment: Why don't you just use `position: relative;` like that - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ndhsLa2q/)?

Comment: @AnonymousXD Because you didn't attach this [CSS library](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css). I add it for you and here is your [output](http://jsfiddle.net/ndhsLa2q/1/). I want to Red-Color-Span placed on that icon.

Comment: Put the icon inside the absolutely positioned span.

Comment: @MrLister This solution will be fine, but just for this example. Actually in reality I can not set `absolutely` position for that icon.

Comment: You still haven't explained why you need absolute for the span. Your updated fiddle looks like it's what you want. So what it wrong with it? Do you want to hide the icon if it's next to the span?

Comment: @MrLister My new updated uses of `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`!!! I don't want to use html space. I want to do that using CSS.

Comment: @MrLister Also I need `absolute` position for that span, because I want that span be on top of (upon) that icon.

Comment: No! Just stop thinking you need `position:absolute`! OK? OK. Here, [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/ndhsLa2q/3/) that doesn't use positioning at all.

Comment: @MrLister Heh, your solution is tricky a bit..! I fear to do that. Because the most my website's visitor use IE (ver 8), and `:not(:empty)` does not work for them, anyway thanks :-)

Comment: OK, [updated fiddle without `:not(:empty)`](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/ndhsLa2q/5/). Sigh.

Comment: @MrLister Look, That's Perfect. Exactly what I wanted. Please write an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to not use absolute positioning, just because you want something else to be hidden. There are other ways too to hide the icon, such as giving it a negative left margin, which will place it under the notification span.

```css
.notification {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 1em;
  position: relative;
}
.notification + i {
  margin-left: -1.25em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<span class='inbox'>
  <span class='notification'></span>
  <i class="fa fa-inbox"></i>
  MyName
</span>
<br>
<br>
<span class='inbox'>
  <span class='notification'>23</span>
  <i class="fa fa-inbox"></i>
  MyName
</span>
<br>
<br>
<span class='inbox'>
  <span class='notification'>4245</span>
  <i class="fa fa-inbox"></i>
  MyName
</span>
```

Please note however, that this depends on the height/width ratio of the icon. For other icons, you will have to change both the notification's min-width and the icon's margin-left.

Answer (score 2):

When you position with `absolute` you remove the element from he document flow, meaning that it's `width` will be ignored from other elements. You can use `position: relative` to position your element which will allow neighboring elements to affecting by it's dimensions. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9f1gun2a/)**.

If you want the `icon` to sit to be "stacked" under the number text, but still not to sit on the `notification` text, then I would restructure your html.

Wrap both the elements that will be stacked inside of a parent element, `div`. And position one of the containing elements as `absolute` (I would recommend the one that will take up the less `width`, which in your example is the `i` element).

In you example, you don't always have the `notification` element, so make sure to use a `min-width` and `min-height` in the `div`, since element within that are positioned absolutely take up no "space."

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ndhsLa2q/4/)**

```css
div {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 16px;
    min-height: 14px;
    position: relative;
}

.notification {
    background-color: red;
    left: 0;
}

i {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span class='inbox'>
    <div>
        <i class="fa fa-inbox"></i>
        <span class='notification'></span>
    </div>
    <span class="text">MyName</span>
</span>
<br>
<br>
<span class='inbox'>
 <div>
  <i class="fa fa-inbox"></i>
     <span class='notification'>23</span>
 </div>
 <span class="text">MyName</span>
<br>
<br>
<span class='inbox'>
    <div>
  <i class="fa fa-inbox"></i>
   <span class='notification'>4245</span>
    </div>
    <span class="text">MyName</span>
</span>
```

Comment: Your first example is wrong. That icon is on top of "MyName".

Comment: @stack Oh, right; I missed that example. I updated the answer to reflect that first one as well.